# friend of the familyname's or familynames

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, double-possessive

Is it

> "John is a friend of the Smith's."

or

> "John is a friend of the Smiths."
>   ?

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: The Smiths are a family; you make the word *Smith* plural by adding an *s*, not with an apostrophe and an *s* as you would for *that smith’s workshop*. Whether the plural noun *Smiths* then needs to be made possessive is a different matter altogether, since both *a friend of Jim* and *a friend of Jim’s* exist. It thus follows that *friend of the Smiths* and *friend of the Smiths’* can also both peacefully coëxist. Certainly your ear cannot tell them apart, only your eye. See the linked answer for more.